# VBA Macro for Excel working incorrectly

Tags: vba, excel

I am working on a macro which does some mathematical calculations and export the data to a row in another sheet in the same excel workbook. 
At the beginning, I wrote a macro which on  button click will export some data to a row in an excel sheet and upon clicking the same button again, it replaces/overwrites the data  previously exported row with the new data but I tried to change the macro such that it exports the data to the next available row instead of overwriting the previous data using the following macro

```
Sub WJArchive()
'
' WJArchive Macro

'
Dim LastCell As Range
Dim LastCellRowNumber As Long


    Set LastCell = ActiveSheet.Cells(ActiveSheet.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp)
    LastCellRowNumber = LastCell.Row + 1

    Sheets("WJ LOGS").Select
    Range("B" & LastCellRowNumber).Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "='Price Sheet'!R4C2"
    Range("C" & LastCellRowNumber).Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "='Price Sheet'!R5C2"
    Range("D" & LastCellRowNumber).Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "='Price Sheet'!R6C2"
    Range("E" & LastCellRowNumber).Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "='Price Sheet'!R8C2"
    Range("F" & LastCellRowNumber).Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "='Price Sheet'!R9C2"
    Range("G" & LastCellRowNumber).Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "='Price Sheet'!R10C2"
    Range("H" & LastCellRowNumber).Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "='Price Sheet'!R11C2"
    Range("I" & LastCellRowNumber).Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "='Price Sheet'!R12C2"
    Range("J" & LastCellRowNumber).Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "='Price Sheet'!R13C2"
    Range("K" & LastCellRowNumber).Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "='Price Sheet'!R14C2"
    Range("L" & LastCellRowNumber).Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "='Price Sheet'!R17C2"
    Range("M" & LastCellRowNumber).Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "='Price Sheet'!R18C2"
    Range("N" & LastCellRowNumber).Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "='Price Sheet'!R19C2"
    Range("O" & LastCellRowNumber).Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "='Price Sheet'!R20C2"
    Range("P" & LastCellRowNumber).Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "='Price Sheet'!R21C2"
    Range("Q" & LastCellRowNumber).Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "='Price Sheet'!R22C2"
    Range("R" & LastCellRowNumber).Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "='Price Sheet'!R23C2"
    Range("S" & LastCellRowNumber).Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "='Price Sheet'!R26C2"
    Range("T" & LastCellRowNumber).Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "='Price Sheet'!R27C2"
    Range("U" & LastCellRowNumber).Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "='Price Sheet'!R28C2"
    Range("V" & LastCellRowNumber).Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "='Price Sheet'!R29C2"
    Range("W" & LastCellRowNumber).Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "='Price Sheet'!R30C2"
    Range("X" & LastCellRowNumber).Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "='Price Sheet'!R31C2"
    Range("Y" & LastCellRowNumber).Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "='Price Sheet'!R32C2"
    Range("Z" & LastCellRowNumber).Select
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 4
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 3
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 2
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 1
    Range("B" & LastCellRowNumber).Select
End Sub
```

For some reasons regardless of what the the last row that is available, the above macro exports the data to row 33 in the excel worksheet on a button click and on a next button click it just replaces the data in row 33 with new data and strangely this works very fine when I run this macro in developer mode when I compile it and assess it with a breakpoint.

The only issue is copying the data to row 33 in design mode.

Not sure, why am getting the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are calculating *LastCellRowNumber* based in the wrong sheet.  Replace:

```
Set LastCell = ActiveSheet.Cells(ActiveSheet.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp)
```

with:

```
Set LastCell = Sheets("WJ LOGS").Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp)
```

Answer (score 3):

Try removing the `Select` and `ActiveCell` methodology. And also add a reference to the Sheet.

E.g., replace

```
Range("H" & LastCellRowNumber).Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "='Price Sheet'!R11C2"
```

with

```
Sheet1.Range("H" & LastCellRowNumber).FormulaR1C1 = "='Price Sheet'!R11C2"
```